# Sending email when cell reach certain value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a spreadsheet that collects data from a Google Form.
When a certain cell's value reach above certain number, I'd like to the sheet to send an email to my account. However I can't seem to get my head around how to do this. I've realized that I can't use the conditional formatting option that I get by right clicking the cell. I can only alter the cell/text color by using that option. Do I have to use a script to be able to perform this task automatically?

(The sheet collects absence/attendance data in a class, and when the absence percentage reach a certain value (15%) I'd like the sheet to e-mail a notice about this.)

This might be a newbie question, but that's what I am; A newbie.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a onFormSubmit trigger on the Response Spreadsheet and after every submit, it can calculate the attendance percentage and send an email using the MailApp.sendMail() method.

```
function calculate(e) 
{  
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var data = s.getDataRange.getValues();

    for (var rows in data) {
     // Calculate the attendance data
    }

    if (condition_met) {
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 
    }

}
```